# Why doesn't Android recognize "BillingClient"

Tags: android, linker, dependencies, billing, billingclient

I am following this guide.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

my build.gradle looks like this:

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0"
implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.0"

androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2"
```

}

The Java code in Android Studios 4 does not have recommended imports for BillingClient

If I try this:
import android.billingclient ...
"billingclient" shows up red / unrecognized.

If I try this:
import androidx.billingclient ...
"billingclient" shows up red / unrecognized.

If I try this:
import import com.android.billingclient ...
"android" shows up red / unrecognized.

I am trying to port a game to Android. I have been stuck on this for days. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Please help!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have figured it out. After literally days.

All it was is "File>Sync Project With Gradle Files"

I am not sure why I didn't need to do this for other statements I added to gradle.